# ng-click not working in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have following two directives. First one (recentisls) creates second one 'issuedesc'

```
directive('recentisls', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {},
            controller: function ($scope, $element) {
                $scope.showIsDsc = function () {                    
                    var el = $compile("<issuedesc></issuedesc>")($scope);
                    $('body').html(el);
            },
            template: '<div ng-click="showIsDsc()"></div>',
        };
    }).

directive('issuedesc', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {},
            controller: function ($scope, $element) {
                $scope.addcomts = function () {
                    alert("A Hello");                    
                };
            },
            template: '<input ng-click="addcomts()" type="button" value="Submit Comments"/>,
            replace: true
        };
    })
```

HTML code -

```
<body>
<issuedesc></issuedesc>
</body>
```

In browser, above works when we click on buttons created from issuedesc.

But,

```
<body>
<recentisls></recentisls>
</body>
```

In browser, above does not work when we click on buttons created from recentisls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were few syntax errors

```
app.directive('recentisls', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.showIsDsc = function () {
                var el = $("<issuedesc></issuedesc>").appendTo('body');
                $compile(el)($scope)
            };

        },
        template: '<div ng-click="showIsDsc()">dd</div>'
    }
}).directive('issuedesc', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.addcomts = function () {
                alert("A Hello");
            };
        },
        template: '<input ng-click="addcomts()" type="button" value="Submit Comments"/>',
        replace: true
    };
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pUsNV/)

Comment: This code works for me - var el = $("<issuedesc></issuedesc>").appendTo('body');
                $compile(el)($scope)

Answer (score 0):

The controller is not the correct place to use $compile and manipulate the DOM. This should be done in the link function. In your case you don't even need to really compile.  You could just incorporate ng-if into your template:

```
<div ng-if="!issueDescriptionVisible" ng-click="showIsDsc()"></div>
<issuedesc ng-if="issueDescriptionVisible"></issuedesc>
```

then your click handler would just do:

```
$scope.showIsDsc = function() {
   $scope.issueDescriptionVisible = true;
}
```